# How do i set all elements of array sequentially to the multiple <p> tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Only last element of an array is getting set to `<p>` tag

Here is my HTML , Javascript , JQuery code

```js
var userInput = "items-carting";
var all_script = "This is the value : ";
var all=$("p:contains(" + userInput + ")").attr('id', 'xyz');
var len_all=$('p').length;
var all_array=[];
for (var i=0; i < len_all; i++) {
  all_array.push($(all[i]).text());
}
all_array = all_array.filter(item => item);
changed_array=[];
for (var i = 0; i < all_array.length; i++) 
{ 
var indexEqu=all_array[i].indexOf("=");
var slicedVal=all_array[i].slice(indexEqu+2,indexEqu+22);
var result = all_array[i].replace(all_array[i],all_script);
var out=result+slicedVal+" to be saved";
changed_array.push(out);
}

for (var j = 0; j < changed_array.length; j++) {
$("#xyz").text(changed_array[j]);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>[items-carting nums="hbn7wxjxjodpxi2nlmml"]</p>
<p>[items-carting nums="nlmmljodhbni27wxjxpx"]</p>
<p>[items-carting nums="bni27wxjnlmmljodhxpx"]</p>
<p>product design</p>
<p>vmware</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Expected output is

```
This is the value : hbn7wxjxjodpxi2nlmml to be saved

This is the value : nlmmljodhbni27wxjxpx to be saved

This is the value : bni27wxjnlmmljodhxpx to be saved

product design

vmware
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs need to be unique

This will work better

```js
const userInput = "items-carting";
// $("p:contains(" + userInput + ")")
// .html((i,text) => `This is the value : ${text.match(/nums="(.*)"/)[1]} to be saved`)

$("p:contains(" + userInput + ")")
 .html(function() { return `This is the value : ${this.textContent.match(/nums="(.*)"/)[1]} to be saved` })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>[items-carting nums="hbn7wxjxjodpxi2nlmml"]</p>
<p>[items-carting nums="nlmmljodhbni27wxjxpx"]</p>
<p>[items-carting nums="bni27wxjnlmmljodhxpx"]</p>
<p>product design</p>
<p>vmware</p>
```

Or if you want it the long way around

```js
var userInput = "items-carting";
var all_script = "This is the value : ";
$("p:contains(" + userInput + ")")
  .addClass('xyz')
  .map((_,item) => item.textContent.trim())
  .get()
  .filter(item => item)
  .map(item => {
    var indexEqu = item.indexOf("=");
    var slicedVal = item.slice(indexEqu + 2, indexEqu + 22);
    var result = item.replace(item, all_script);
    return result + slicedVal + " to be saved";
  })
  .forEach((item, i) => $(".xyz").eq(i).text(item));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>[items-carting nums="hbn7wxjxjodpxi2nlmml"]</p>
<p>[items-carting nums="nlmmljodhbni27wxjxpx"]</p>
<p>[items-carting nums="bni27wxjnlmmljodhxpx"]</p>
<p>product design</p>
<p>vmware</p>
```

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan ,
Is there anyway to use alternate for this line .filter(item => item).map(item =>{
because its giving me ECMA error in arrow function.
How can i convert this arrow function to the regular one ?

Comment: See updated script

Comment: Thank you very much .
In place of return `This is the value : i have to put <!-- This site is converting visitors into subscribers --!><script>(function(d,u,ac){var s=d.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript'</script>  
this line
But as this contains html comment and <script> this is difficult to enclose in double or single quotes.
But Thanks for your answer .